# django group query by day with timezone specification

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime

I have a model with datetime field saved in UTC:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    ...
```

I need to count number of orders per day for last 30 days to represent it with plot.

```
time_zone = 'Europe/Kiev'

date_to = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ' 23:59:59'
date_from = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=29)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ' 00:00:00'
date_range = (date_from, date_to)

data = Order.objects.filter(
           created__range=date_range
       ).extra(
           {'date': "date(created) AT TIME ZONE '{0}'".format(time_zone)}
       ).values('date').annotate(items=Count('id'))
```

But this call still groups data by day in UTC which is wrong. I can simply check that by counting number of orders in specific day:

```
data = Order.objects.filter(
           created_range=('2016-05-03 00:00:00', '2016-05-03 23:59:59')
       ).count()
```

Is there any way to make database group items with timezone correctly in one call, because looping through 30 days and making 30 calls is slow?

Working with django 1.8.7 and postgres 9.4.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, there were some mistakes in extra({...}).

So

```
extra({'date': "date(created) AT TIME ZONE '{0}'".format(time_zone)}
```

Should be changed to

```
extra(select={'date': "date(goods_order.created AT TIME ZONE '{0}')".format(time_zone))
```

where `goods_order.created` is *database*_*tablename*.*fieldname*